# Declaring URL in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, url, swift3

How can I declare a URL in swift 3?

This is my attempted code:

```
var messageURL: URL = URL()
```

OR

```
var messageURL: Foundation.URL = URL()
```

This is the error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'URL' with no arguments

Here's some documentation (Swift 3.0) from Apple that I'm having trouble implementing:

> Properties whose name conflicts with Foundation types after removing their NS prefix will lead to module-qualified type names. For example, if there is a var URL: NSURL, it will be rewritten as var URL: Foundation.URL

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Swift 3 has `URL` (a `struct`) and `NSURL` (a `class`, which it inherits from ObjC). The situation is like `String` and `NSString`. You have 2 options to approach this:

1: If you know the URL at the time of declaration:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
```

2: If you can only find out about the URL later:

```
var url: URL!

// You can check if the variable is initialized by checking it against nil:
//     if url == nil { /* not initialized */ }

// When you are ready to assign it a value:
url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension URL {
    init(_ string: String) {
        self.init(string: "\(string)")!
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var unwrappedURL = URL("https://www.google.com")
```

This will help us to avoid unwrapping the URL everywhere in the code base

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 URL has many initializers but all of them take an argument, either string or data.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue when I migrated to Swift 3 but, after being stuck, I find realized that I made a class before migration called `URL` which was now interfering with Foundation's `URL` struct and making issues.